# Maximum Number of Serial Communications

Tags: arduino, serial-port, serial-communication, rxtx

Aside from Software Serial (Library) and the Serial that is meant to configure the unit (i.e: to burn the bootloader); my device (**Arduino Nano**) has 4 Serial Communication pins.

**RX0/TX0** and **RX1/TX1.**

Considering Arduino allows only 1 Serial Communication (Hardware or Software Serial): 
If I use the Hardware Serial Pins "0" pins; will I still be able to use Hardware Serial Pins "1" at the same time?

Comment: Uno and classic Nano have only one Serial and that is connected to USB. what wireless communication?

Answer (score -1):

This [A Single Arduino Uno with 14 RS-232 Ports](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/phpoc_man/a-single-arduino-uno-with-14-rs-232-ports-a812ce) may be useful for you